# How to populate DOJO Select with JSON containing arbitrary parameters instead of label and value

Tags: javascript, json, select, dojo

I would like to populate a DOJO select with a JSON where item values for `value` are expressed by `code`. An example is:

```
//require dojo Select

var select = new Select({
    name: "stateSelect",                                    
    options: [ { display: '1', code: 'TN', label: 'Tennessee' },
               { display: '2',code: 'VA', label: 'Virginia'},
               { display: '3',code: 'WA', label: 'Washington' },
               { display: '4',code: 'FL', label: 'Florida' },
               { display: '5',code: 'CA', label: 'California' }]                                    
    }, "stateSelect");
    select.startup();
}
```

But it's not working. However, having `value` in place of `code` (what DOJO wants as id value) works. But my JSON comes with `code` (plus `display` and `label`) tags. I believe the order should not be a problem, since we are talking about JSON, but probably DOJO demands for `value` parameters. Could you please clarify tags position requirements and how to specify that I want DOJO to take my `code` tag for its `value`? Replacement of the string is not an acceptable solution, because the system needs the `code` value of my items for many other functions.

Documentation: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/form/Select.html

**EDIT: IMPORTANT. I have noticed that the tags are specified WITHOUT quot. marks (""). But my JSON has them (e.g. "code": "product1"... and not code: "product1"). How can I handle this?**

Answer (score 1):

When provided with an options array Select expects `value` and `label`. You don't have to rename the `code` property, you can just copy it to `value` or create another array (if it doesn't cause too much trouble for the rest of your application).

However Select can also be created with a store instead of an options array. Stores can generally define their id property. ItemFileReadStore (dojo 1.6) expects an object with the following structure:

```
{
    "identifier": "abbreviation",
    "label": "name",
    "items": [
        { "abbreviation": "AL", "name": "Alabama" },

        ... other 48 states here ...

        { "abbreviation": "WY", "name": "Wyoming" }
    ]
}
```

You can find more information in this documentation link: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/selects_using_stores/